# Importing Omnigraffle drawings into a NeoOffice document

Tags: macos, omnigraffle, neooffice

What is the best way to import an Omnigraffle drawing into a NeoOffice document? I expect the document to change over time, and I may need to update the drawing later, so I'd like a way to make that happen painlessly.

Currently, I export the drawing to a .jpg and then import that in NeoOffice with Insert->Picture->From File... but that's an extra step and extra file to maintain (the intermediate .jpg) and the frame that NeoOffice puts the image in always gives me trouble when I try to update the image with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Use Neo-/Open-Office's native Draw program.

Or, leave a temporary JPG in the NeoOffice document until you're done editing the Omnigraffle document.